# vb.net Desktop Application not running on a client machine after installation

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, sql-server-2014

I have created an application in vb.net using sql server database and crystal reports, I then created the setup file using visual studio 2015 installer extension and installed the project on my Computer from which the application was developed and it is working fine. The issue starts when I install in the client computer, the application does not even start in the client machine, I have installed the .netFramework required and crystal reports run time engine in the client machine but still the app is not starting.

I have a background worker on my startup form and the connection is tested on form load. If the connection is successful the applications the creates a crystal report from a table in the database and if connection is not successful, the application loads the configuration form to manually configure the connection string and a message box will show the exception occurred.

Below is the code

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class loader
Dim connection As SqlConnection

  Private Sub loader_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
       
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            ShowPanel([Panel2])
            LoaderReportLoading([CrystalReportViewer1])
        End If

    End Sub

    Delegate Sub LoadRpt(ByVal [crv] As Object)
    Delegate Sub SetPanelVisible(ByVal [panel] As Panel)

    Private Sub LoaderReportLoading(ByVal [crv] As Object)                     'use the same delegate LoadRpt 
        Try
            If My.Settings.connection = "" Then
                server_configuration.ShowDialog()
            Else
                connection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.connection)
                connection.Open()
                Dim CoTable As New DataTable
                Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM COMPANY", connection)
                    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                    adapter.Fill(CoTable)
                End Using
                Dim rep As New loaderReport
                rep.Database.Tables("COMPANY").SetDataSource(CoTable)

                If [crv].InvokeRequired Then
                    Dim myDelegate As New LoadRpt(AddressOf LoaderReportLoading)

                    Me.Invoke(myDelegate, New Object() {crv})

                Else
                    [crv].ReportSource = rep
                End If
                connection.Close()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "The following Error Occured While Connecting to the database")

            server_configuration.ShowDialog()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub ShowPanel(ByVal [panel] As Panel)
        If [panel].InvokeRequired Then
            Dim myDelegate As New SetPanelVisible(AddressOf ShowPanel)

            Me.Invoke(myDelegate, New Object() {panel})

        Else
            [panel].Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I don't have any idea of using windows event logs, this is my first desktop application to be deployed.

Comment: What sort of logging have you got built in?  How are you specifying the sql connection, is the sql instance available from your client machine.  Anything in the windows event logs?

Comment: The sqlconnection is specified on the client machine and I am using only message box to show the errors.

Comment: @Seru what are you displaying in the message box when the error occurs?  Maybe you could to update your question with the appropriate startup code from your app so we can see potential trouble spots

Comment: Okay thanx let me update the question and put some code in my startup form

Comment: The Sql Server engine also has to be installed. Additionally, Sql Server (as the name implies) is a _server class_ database. It's intended to run on a dedicated machine, and wants to use up extra resources on that machine for things like caching and optimization _all the time_... even when you application is _not running_. It's a **great** server database, but a _really poor choice_ for a local desktop application.

Comment: Also: Visual Studio 2015 and Sql Server 2014 are both **really old**. There are _much_ newer editions of both available _for free_.

Comment: What database engine do you suggest? @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. Sqlite, VistaDB, Sql Server local instance, and even MS Access can all work well here.

Comment: Database engine aside, It's still going to be helpful to know exactly what that exception is that you're getting.  Haven't actually tried your code, but the way you've implemented that background worker seems horribly over complicated, and I'm not even sure that it's going to work as you're expecting as it looks to be attempting to do UI stuff.

Comment: The background worker is updating some components on the ui, I've implemented it to avoid freezing of the application

Comment: @Seru yeah,  that’s the exact point I’m trying to make.  Background workers aren’t supposed to be used like that.  Maybe have a look document for the events of background workers.  These events make it quite easy to pass data between the bgw and ui threads

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the error after implementing logging on my system. The error was with the runtime engine for crystal reports. I changed a version of the crystal reports from SP30 to SP26 and all is working fine now.